# Access/Receive a value from AppDelegate.m inside React Native App

Tags: ios, react-native, appdelegate

I have a value formed inside the AppDelegate.m file and I need to access it inside my React Native iOS app.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSLog(@"My token: %@", deviceToken);
  [RCTPushNotificationManager application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

I want this `deviceToken` inside my app. How to access this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a listener for the *register* event. Best place for that is in the componentDidMount method of your root component.

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', this.onDeviceToken);
```

In *onDeviceToken* you receive the token as only parameter and can process and/or store it.

Check out the example in the documentation for the *notification* event. Works exactly the same.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#examples